# ObjectMapper Mock queda nulo en clase de Test

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Estoy teniendo un problema. Tengo una clase abstracta a la cual le inyecto sus dependencias. Todas se crean bien menos el ObjectMappr de Jackson.

Clase Abstracta:

```
protected final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

private final String apiName;

@Autowired private MeliRestClient restClient;

public AbstractClientRepository(String apiName) {
  this.apiName = apiName;
  objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
}
```

Clase de test:

```
  @Mock
  private MeliRestClient restClient;

  @Mock
  private MeliRequestBuilder requestBuilderMock;

  @Mock
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @InjectMocks
  private static AbstractClientRepository abstractClientRepository;

  private static final String poolName = "pool";

  @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() throws RestException {
    RoutingHelper.setMeliContext(MeliContextBuilder.build(Collections.emptyMap()));
    abstractClientRepository = Mockito.mock(
      AbstractClientRepository.class,
      Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
  }
```

Resultado:
[image: Clase de test]

Como ven, el restClient se mockea y se inyecta correctamente, pero el objeto ObjectMapper no.
Algun consejo?

Gracias!

Comment: ya que usas spring lo primero es entender que la forma en que opera es por reflexión, y que el comportamiento básico es usar el constructor sin argumentos. intenta declarar un bean en tu configuración para tu object mapper e inyéctalo. Igual cambia de inyección en propiedades con autowired por inyección en el constructor tus pruebas unitarias y el mismo spring te lo agradecerán